# Adding System Objects to a Hash Table or Array

Tags: .net, powershell

** I found this self-elevating script online a while back. Though I've made some changes to it over time, I cant help but wonder if there's a way to add system objects to a hash table or array for better processing. **

I've been able to add these items to an array and a hash table, but it doesn't exactly make the code a whole lot shorter?

http://www.expta.com/2017/03/how-to-self-elevate-powershell-script.html

I've updated it to be a little more compact, I've tested it internally and it works, but suppose it could also be used elsewhere...

```
$0 = [Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent(),
     [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]'Administrator', [int](Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).BuildNumber ,
     "-File `"" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand + "`" " + $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments

if ( $0[0].IsInRole($0[1]) ) { Set-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Scope Process -Force ; echo "Granted" }
elseif     ( $0[2] -ge 6000) 
{ 
    Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell.exe -Verb Runas -Args $0[3] 
    if ( $? -eq $true ) { echo "Script was elevated to Administrator Access"            }
    else                { echo "Access Denied" ; Read-Host "Press Enter to exit" ; Exit }
}
```

The project that prompted me to come to Stack Overflow for the first time about 6 months ago, has been updated as of 5/18/2019.

https://github.com/secure-digits-plus-llc/Hybrid-DesiredStateController

I've been implementing the things I learn... and here is a video of the project's current state... I'm making some loop changes and then I will be making yet another new video shortly, including a post user migration portion as well.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVsviPCg4Vk

I could use some development partners or advice on how to better build my processes. I've been toying with cmdletbindings but I'm not ready to include them yet. The process totally bypasses the need for task sequences into the MDT tool since my template will enable access to a read only domain account. I will be doing more Active Directory integration, but for now, I'd settle for some beta testers.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem.

Comment: I think you should be more clear what you mean by "these things".

Comment: I want to add system objects that show up as green or calling methods into a hash table. Some of them work, some of them don't.

[PSCustomObject] seems to increase the speed of these operations and that's what I'm trying to add them to. Is it possible or no?

Comment: Why compact the code to such a degree that it is barely readable?